# Uninstall nodenv from boxen

Tags: macos, puppet, boxen

Boxen installs nodenv in `/opt/boxen/nodenv`. Is it ok to uninstall it **simply removing the nodenv directory**?

```
rm -rf /opt/boxen/nodenv
```

I wish to do a clean install, re-running boxen. I could nuke the all boxen installation, but I'm wondering if this can be done in a less dramatic way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking over the repo, it looks like there's no way to perform the standard `ensure => absent` to remove the `nodenv` setup using Boxen. [I've opened an issue for that](https://github.com/boxen/puppet-nodejs/issues/45), because it should be a way to ensure absent.

For now, you could:

- Remove the code referencing nodenv

Probably looks like this in your manifest/site.pp:

```
  # node versions
  nodejs::version { 'v0.6': }
  nodejs::version { 'v0.8': }
  nodejs::version { 'v0.10': }
```

- Add some code like this:

  ```
  file {"${boxen::config::home}/nodenv":
    ensure => absent,
  }
  ```

Which will make sure that the nodenv directory is absent. It's basically doing the same thing as `rm -rf /opt/boxen/nodenv` that you mention, but in a more idempotent and Puppet-y way.